# How do I get meaningful error messages in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, message

I have moved this question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/143223/how-do-i-get-meaningful-error-messages-in-iis7) where it is probably more appropriator.

I have a classic ASP website that is crashing in IIS7.
It is crashing because IIS doesn't allow file uploads greater than a certain size. I know this because files below about 200k work fine.
I removed the Status Code 500 error in IIS but I still don't get a file name and the line where my code failed as I do when running locally.

Instead I get:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
occurred.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out 
more about this error.
```

How do I get a file name and the line where my code failed?

Here are my IIS settings:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/errors.png))</sub>

**AND THE ANSWER FROM SERVERFAULT IS...**

Login as an admin on the IIS server, open IIS 7 Manager, the open the Asp icon under the Web site you want to change the error messages for (it'll be on the right with all the other icons; it's the first one).

Scroll down and change Send Errors To Browser to True. Might have to iisreset, not sure.

Comment: Have you done it on the right IIS7 Header? If you select the last one - then ensure your on the same box. If you can use the server in a localhost, try Remote desktop'ing to it and then you'll be able to see the error output.

Answer (score 2):

Detailed error messages its called. Very helpful during testing

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/19/Improving-Custom-Errors-for-IIS7-Server.aspx

Comment: I changed the IIS setting to "Detailed errors" but I am still not getting a detailed error. Also tried stopping and starting IIS.

Comment: Actually this is plain old ASP

Comment: Most of the information in that post is in images, all of which are dead links.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly answer to your question about error page, but if you have problem with uploading big files, you probably should change AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed settings in IIS.
http://forums.iis.net/t/1130837.aspx